# How to know elapsed time of a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job in which at the end of the job (maybe around post actions or in the last stage of that job I want to find how much time has been elapsed since the job started.

How can find that? Is there any easy straightforward way of knowing it ?

Comment: try `${currentBuild.durationString}` in the last line pf the `post` stage.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Timestamper plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/).

The Timestamper plugin adds timestamps to the console output of Jenkins jobs. For example:

```
21:51:15  Started by user anonymous
21:51:15  Building on master
21:51:17  Finished: SUCCESS
```

> `/timestamps/` By default, display the elapsed time in seconds with three places after the decimal point.
>
> `/timestamps/?time=HH:mm:ss&appendLog` Display the system clock time and append the line from the log.
>
> `/timestamps/?elapsed=HH:mm:ss.S&appendLog` Display the elapsed time and append the line from the log.
>
> `/timestamps/?time=HH:mm:ss&elapsed=HH:mm:ss.S` Display both the system clock time and the elapsed time.
>
> `/timestamps/?currentTime&time=HH:mm:ss` Display the current time on the Jenkins controller.

Comment: can you please provide example for declarative pipeline to show elapsed time?

Comment: @arunas-bartisius, It's [in the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/timestamper/).

Comment: it's not, as I mean declarative pipeline and NOT timestamps, but elapsed time. If you amend answer with declarative example +1 from me. agent any ... timestamps() shows timestamp, not elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

Sample pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
                sleep 10
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            println "${currentBuild.durationString}"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello)
[Pipeline] echo
Hello World
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
14 sec and counting
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

if you don't like the `and counting` part you can always do

```
"${currentBuild.durationString}".replaceAll(' and counting', "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the answers above there is a very nice way of doing it:

```
import hudson.Util
.
.
.
String time = Util.getTimeSpanString(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentBuild.startTimeInMillis)
```

If you display `time` it will come in this format:

```
2 hr 15 min 47 sec
```

which is pretty neat and does not require any extra variable to be setup initially, also less editing needed (in my case I wanted in this exact way).